# IIS not finding an external DLL

Tags: c#, .net, iis, dll, asp.net-core

I have a C# .NET Core WebAPI and I'm using IIS. In my code I load an external DLL at runtime, like this:

```
var res = new LoadMyDLL("mydll.dll");
```

I have to do it because the `LoadMyDLL` function accepts a string which is the path to the DLL itself. Ideally I'd like to have the DLL in the same folder as the main app so that's why no path is provided, just the name of the dll file.

Now, when I run the application in console mode everything is file, the dll is in the same folder of the main .exe. When I run the application as a class library in IIS it doesn't find the dll anymore. What's the working dir when running under IIS? What could be a post build step in VS2015 to copy the dll into the correct IIS folder?

Comment: should be in the `bin` folder. that is where the binaries are usually exported to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ASP.NET websites, the root directory is the project directory. If it's hosted in IIS, there should be a web.config inside it.

Here you can put where your library DLLs will be copied:

[image: Here you can put where your library DLLs will be copied]

Comment: ok thanks, it's hosted in IIS. Could you please elaborate more about the web.config? I have one indeed

Comment: Web.config keeps the IIS settings for that website. For ASP.NET Core it is only needed if it's hosted inside IIS.

Comment: So given my app is hosted on IIS, what's the working dir?

Comment: Working dir is the root folder of the project, the same dir where you find the web.config.